# Firebase Cloud Functions deploy fails

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions, firebase-console, firebase-tools

After a month of successful deploying the functions deploy of new functions to Firebase database started to fail. The process halts at the point `functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...` and eventually stops when token expires. Running deploy with `--debug` flag does not give more info. I tried both deploying new code and reusing old functions on new DB nodes.

Could someone please give me a hint on what happens on this stage of deploy?

Is there a limit for the number of deployed functions I missed?

Upd: Problem solved by updating firebase-tools from 3.5.0 to 3.7.0

Comment: Problem solved by updating firebase-tools from 3.5.0 to 3.7.0